# jquery addClass incorrect syntax?

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table representing the board in a board game app. It has an arbitrary number of rows and columns with 'td' elements representing game squares.

I'm trying to populate a number of 'class = play' board squares with a small number of 'class = hasAtoms' at random locations. Console.log commands show the initial selector returns a reasonable number of objects and 'rnd' is a valid random number, but the final console.log fails to detect any 'class = hasAtom' objects - any suggestions please ?

```
function placeAtoms(numberOfAtoms) {
    var rnd, len;
    do {
        len = $('#board .play:not(.hasAtom)').length;
        rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * len) + 1);
        $($(this).get(rnd)).addClass('hasAtom');
        numberOfAtoms--;
    } while (numberOfAtoms > 0);
    console.log($('#board .play .hasAtom').length + ' squares have atoms');
}
```

Comment: Just a note, but `$($(this).get(rnd)).addClass()` can be `$(this).eq(rnd).addClass()`

Comment: What does `this` refer to ? How are you calling `placeAtoms`? Also, in the first selector, you are looking for `.play` elements that don't have a class `.hasAtom` (`.play:not(.hasAtom)`). After the loop, you have looking for `.hasAtom` elements that are *descendants* of `.play` elements (`.play .hasAtom`). The second one should probably be `.play.hasAtom` instead.

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML as well. It seems that the problem lies in the $(this) selector

Comment: placeAtoms is called by the Javascript game driving function immediately after the board has been created. My intention was that the 'this' in the placeAtoms function refers to the selector comprising the right hand side of the 'len' assignment statement above it

Comment: The game board HTLM  is generated in Javascript into a string and jquery is used to inject this into the DOM

Comment: $(this) will not work because it is undefined. You need to pass a parameter for that.

Comment: @poweruser: That's not how `this` works.  `this` is set via how the function is called.  It's the function's "context".  Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the $(this) selector. You need to either declare it or pass in a parameter for it. Assuming you want a random ".play" child inside the "#board" element container, I would try this:

```
    function placeAtoms(numberOfAtoms) {
        var rnd, len;
        do {
            len = $('#board .play:not(.hasAtom)').length;
            rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * len) + 1);
            $($("#board .play").eq(rnd)).addClass('hasAtom');
            numberOfAtoms--;
        } while (numberOfAtoms > 0);
        console.log($('#board .hasAtom').length + ' squares have atoms');
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest `$("#board .play").eq(rnd).addClass('hasAtom')`.  That's cleaner than `$($("#board .play").get(rnd))`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `$("#board .play:not(.hasAtom)").eq(rnd).addClass('hasAtom')`?

Comment: He/She would have to decide this depending on what they need for their application.